# Organic Groups - Include nodes as part if it on group creation

Tags: organic-groups

I'm looking for at way to make some nodes, eg. "About us", part of the Organic Group.

```
/
/about-us*
/more-general-stuff
```

When I create the OG I want the nodes marked with * to be part of the group.

```
/my-group
/my-group/about-us
/my-group/another-page-for-the-group
```

/my-group/about-us is a copy of /about-us, and if you edit /about-us it also updates /my-group/about-us.

/my-group/about-us could contain blocks specific for the group.

So when I tried to use views to create a page on /%/about-us, I'm not able to put blocks on that "page".

Any ideas is welcome.

Comment: I ended up using relations for this, I create on "referral node" that via a relation fetches the data form the main node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rules to generate the nodes upon creation of the group.  If you haven't worked with Rules it is an incredibly powerful module and is well worth the time investment to learn its intricacies.